# How to use several useEffect Hooks in one component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Ok, I'm completely new with hooks, and so far managed to create a component:

```
const Dashboard = ({
  getCurrentReport,
  auth: { user },
  report: { report, loading }
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentReport();
  }, [getCurrentReport]);
  return loading && report === null ? (
    <Spinner />
  ) : (
    <div className="dashboard-container">
      {!report && (
        <span className="main-text">
          make a report
        </span>
      )}
      {!report && (
        <Link className="create-button" to="/report">
          Create Report
        </Link>
      )}
      {report && (
        <Fragment>
          <div className="num-container">
            <span className="main-text">num of days: </span>
            <div className="num-number">
              <span className="header-text">
                5
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

What I need here is to calculate the difference of 2 dates, the one is `report.startDate` accessible from the redux state, and the other is `today` (now Date()). The example of the report.startDate value is `2020-03-22T20:00:00.000Z`

Since I don't understand hooks completely yet, I can't figure out where to write a function in the component above that would calculate the difference in days, and that would render the calculated amount instead of the number `5`.

What do I have to use here? Another useEffect?

Comment: do you want that value to be rendered just one? or be updated in live(countdown?)?

Comment: No, I just need one value, that is the difference in between today and the report.startDate

Comment: then just render it inline without any `useEffect`

Comment: Then I get "Objects are not valid React child components".

Comment: Ok, managed to do that!

Answer (score 0):

```
             <span className="header-text">
                {Number(
                  (new Date().getTime() / 1000 -
                    moment(report.startDate)
                      .toDate()
                      .getTime() /
                      1000) /
                    86400
                ).toFixed()}
              </span>
```

This helped to get what I need. However, I'm sure there's gotta be a better way to this, and will be happy handle the right answer to the one who helps to refactor the code.